# Trying to setObject of type Number in NSMutableDictionary and get strange warning

Tags: iphone, compiler-warnings, nsmutabledictionary, nsnumber

I'm Trying to setObject in NSMutableDictionary and get strange warning hear is the code

```
if ([errorCode intValue] != -1) {
    NSLog(@"after getting data back");
    NSString *userName = [[protocol3Replay valueForKeyPath:uName]autorelease];
    NSString *userPassword = [[protocol3Replay valueForKeyPath:pass]autorelease];
    NSNumber *UserId = [[protocol3Replay valueForKeyPath:@"Session.user_id"]autorelease];
    NSNumber *customerId = [[protocol3Replay valueForKeyPath:@"Session.customer_id"]autorelease];

    BOOL b = [file checkFile];
    NSLog(@"after check file exists");
    if (b == YES) {
       NSLog(@"file exist"); 
        NSMutableDictionary *fileDic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];

        fileDic = [file readFile];

        [fileDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UserId] forKey:@"user_id"];
        [fileDic  setObject:token forKey:@"device_token"];
        [fileDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:customerId] forKey:@"customer_id"];
        [fileDic setObject:userName forKey:@"user_name" ];
        [fileDic setObject:userPassword forKey:@"user_password" ];

    }
```

the waning si:warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

way is that?

Comment: Help us, which line is the error on? What about the error message do you not understand?

Comment: BTW, Your code:

'NSMutableDictionary *fileDic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
    fileDic = [file readFile];'

is flawed. The second line assigns the result of `[file readFile]` making the allocation of `fileDic` in the first line irrelevant. Suggestion: use ARC, it is available in iOS 4 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `UserID` to `numberWithInteger:`, which takes an `NSInteger`. It's nothing to do with the `setObject:`. You probably want to either copy `UserID` or just pass in `UserID` to `setObject:` directly.

Answer (score 1):

UserID is an OBJECT and the parameter for numberWithInteger is an NSInteger which is just an integer. NSInteger is NOT a subclass of NSNumber or NSObject. It isn't an pointer, it is an integer.

So your declaration NSNumber *UserID = ... should be NSInteger userID (no * because it's not a pointer).

p.s. This is only one possible way to fix your problem.

Comment: Tried to write:NSNumber UserId = [[protocol3Replay valueForKeyPath:@"Session.user_id"]autorelease]; it was marked as error

Comment: That's because, as I said, NSNumber is not an object, it's an integer. Autorelease is not a method for integers. Secondly, in every statement where you're calling valueForKey and then sending the message autorelease is incorrect. You only send autorelease to objects that are retained.